# Origin of -tai desiderative suffix

Tags: etymology, suffixes, auxiliaries

Japanese verbs can take the suffix -tai, which attaches to the ren'youkei form and turns the verb into an -i adjective, expressing desire to do what the verb says. I have recently wondered where this suffix comes from. Is it known? I mean, do we know where the -tai suffix in question comes from? Someone proposed it might be from -te + ai, love, as a comparison with how "oi", to love, means also to want in Hakka. Could that be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this article](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%B8%8C%E6%9C%9B_%28%E8%A8%80%E8%AA%9E%E5%AD%A6%29) in Japanese WP, -たい is the descendant of Middle Japanese -たし (-tasi), which ultimately traces back to Old Japanese (or Proto-Japonic) いたし (itasi; "sore, acute").

[A paper referred by that page](http://ci.nii.ac.jp/naid/40019009531) argues that this form has changed its meaning taking the path of "painful" → "sorely felt" → "of physiological necessity" → "of emotional necessity" → "desire".

> *Someone proposed it might be from -te + ai, love*...

It's unlikely to be true considering the oldest attested form of this word ended in -asi, not -ai. Additionally, if Japanese speakers want to incorporate Chinese words in such a way, they never use *te*-form but append them directly to word stem or 連用形. For instance, -そう in 「雨{あめ}が降{ふ}りそう」 is said to originate from 相{そう} ("appearance").

Comment: If ai is a Chinese loanword, what would the "indigenous", "original" Japanese word for love be? Perhaps koi?

Comment: And "ame ga orisou"... "looks like it's raining / going to rain"?

Comment: (1) Yes, the indigenous word for love should be "koi" (lit. "yearning"). "Ai" for "love" is relatively new, being an outcome of modern translation from Western languages. (2) It's "furisou"... I think I'd put furiganas on it. Your translation is correct.

Comment: Stupid Google Translate had me miscorrecting my transliteration :).

Comment: @broccolifacemask, what of 愛づ【めづ】 (modern 愛でる【めでる】) as another Old Japanese word for "to love"?

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi Nice catch. I wouldn't say it exactly means "romantic love", but matches up very well with English _love_.